# itextsharp creating a corrupt / blank pdf file, i-9 file

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-2.0, itext

I have been using Itextsharp for prefilling the fillable pdfs in .aspx pages. But when I am trying to do the exact same thing with i-9 file (downloaded from dept of homeland security), its giving me a size 0 file, which couldnt be opened (i get an error msg saying, its a corrupted file).

I am just copying the code snippet (I have all the necessary Itestsharp references in my solution) which is generating a corrupt pdf file (size 0)

```
string pdfTemplate = @"c:\PDF\i-9.pdf";
  string newFile = @"c:\PDF\completed_i-9.pdf";
  PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
  PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(
                                                               newFile, FileMode.Create));
  pdfStamper.Close();
```

However, if I do the same thing with any other fillable pdfs e.g. w4 it works perfectly fine. Any idea guys, what is going wrong in here?

Thanks

Comment: Try saving the i-9 file with an older Acrobat and see if iText can read it; it could be a compatibility issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I understood you correctly - this is what I did. I un-installed the current version of acrobat reader (which was 9+) and installed with acrobat 8. Opened the file i-9 and saved a copy of it (by doing save as>>). But I still get the same error. What bugs me the most it that it works perfectly fine with other pdf files (which are saved in same version) e.g. w4.  Is there something inherently wrong with i-9? Can I somehow recreate this pdf? Thanks.

Comment: If you hit ctrl+d and click on the security tab, you'll see that the PDF is secured.  Check my answer below for further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah.  Having [tracked down the PDF](http://www.uscis.gov/files/form/i-9.pdf), I see the problem.  It has a blank open password, but none the less has some document security.

iText's security implementation isn't fine-grained enough (yet) to allow some things and not others, so we throw an exception when you open a password protected PDF file (the open password to this PDF is an empty string, which opens automatically, but its still there) unless you open it with the OWNER password, in which case anything goes.

If you check your logs, you'll see the exception.

Only Homeland Security knows the owner password, and I doubt they'll tell you.  The good news is that someone else asked a more specific "how can I use iText to modify a file with an "open" password" type question and figured it out for themselves.

Using their answer however, is Legally Questionable, so I'm not going to provide a link or tell you the answer (which I already knew, and didn't tell the other questioner either).

Comment: Thank you very much Mark! Yes soon after posting the question, I figured it out that the document has security settings enabled, not allowing "content copying" etc [I missed it out in the beg since it didn't ask any pwd].  
The question is - why did they put a restriction of such kind? Is there any other way to programatically pre-fill the pdf? Thanks again.